# iPhone details edit views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am fairly new to the iPhone app creating scene. I have viewed some of Apple's presentations about this and read a few pages in the iOS development center. I managed to display a list of values stored in a .plist in a table view.

If you press an item you switch to the detail editing view and I was wondering if there is a way to use like the main table cell views used commonly in existing iOS applications like here:

[image]

Is there a way to use these toggle/select value table cell views or am I forced to create my own xib files?

EXTRA: I tried to search for code examples on the apple website but could not really find one that implemented this sort of view. If anyone knows an example using this, please link me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to do this in XIB files, but you can to it in code in the tableview delegate method named: cellForRowAtIndex path. The you use the cell-reference you have in this method and say

```
cell.accessoryView = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

You could of course made a reference to this switch and added a listener and so on.

But there is not a standard cell type in IOS that implements this behavior.

**Requested in comment**

```
 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    self.accessoryView = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: If I would want to do this inside a class that is extending UITableViewCell, in what method should I do this?